# Find process to convert hex to decimal if in/output is known

Tags: hex, decimal

If I know that a *known* hexadecimal string should, after undergoing some unknown conversions (bitwise operations/bit shifting/simple hex->dec), give me a *known* decimal string, what would be the best process to find out how each of those hex strings gets converted?

Examples:

```
00042fd584 should become 60098
000645e6c6 -> 62307
0006455beb -> 44533
00042fd518 -> 60044
```

I'm **not** looking for a direct solution here; I would like to know if a process exists by which *I* can find out how I can convert my hex strings to the right dec strings. I'm basically asking how to reverse-engineer some algorithm that crunches numbers and/or strings in some unknown way if I know both my inputs and (expected) outputs.

Comment: NOTE: I have no idea which stackexchange page this question belongs in (if any at all), I was considering putting this in the math page. I may need it to be migrated...

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I'm coding in Python for the project to which this question is relevant

Comment: @underscore_d I flagged it myself

Comment: Hopefully that or some of the similar threads have some useful info.  If you're dealing with a hashing algorithm, then you might be in luck. However, if any kind of encryption, salting, etc is involved, then unless the implementer of the algorithm goofed while coding it, it's probably unlikely to be crackable. Either way, without a bit more context, it's probably hard for anyone to start helping. But anyway, good luck!